# Android app icon / ic_launch icon has white padding

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, appicon

Generated an app icon using
https://appicon.co/

Ive used this before for other apps and its working great but this time my app icon has white padding on android OS, , any idea why ?

Im using react native & already added assets to android native side

[app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSEd8.png)

How icon looks on android home

[icon on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07DZr.png)

Comment: That site does not look like it supports [adaptive launcher icons](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive), which have been standard on Android since 8.0 or 8.1.

Comment: Im aware of adaptive icons, but its not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is because the icon I'm using has transparent background. IOS did add white bg by default and handled it, android handled it by rapping the icon with white padding also.

Fixed after changing background to be white.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [this](https://icon.kitchen/) website to generate icons before uploading the image here make sure your icon doesn't have any transparent padding.
I've used this website multiple times works perfectly.

Comment: What a great and easy tool to use, thank you!